# Cakephp find joining two columns

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp, find

I have a BD that contains people with day and month fields, like so:

person1 (day = 5; month = 3)

person2 (day = 2; month = 12)

I have to perform a find between 2 dates, for example, I need all people between 01/03 and 01/06 (day/month) but I don't know how to perform that.

I tried using separate conditions, like this:

```
$conditions['People.day >='] = dayA;
$conditions['People.month >='] = monthA;
$conditions['People.day <='] = dayB;
$conditions['People.month <='] = monthB;
```

But, that's not correct because it finds day and month, I mean, it finds People between monthA and monthB and People between dayA and dayB, instead, what I need is people between dayA/monthA and dayB/monthB

I suppose I must do some kind of a JOIN, but I'm lost here, I looked some information but I don't know where to start.

**updated info:**

ok, I'm using this

```
Array
(
    [People.month_day BETWEEN ? AND ?] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/02
            [1] => 28/02
        )

)
```

but I get people like this:
1/1
2/1
10/1
11/1
12/1
13/1
20/1
21/1
1/2

what's wrong? do you need more code? I'm using this to retrieve results:
A paginate:

```
public $paginate = array('People'=>array(
        'limit' => 16,
        'order' => 'People.month, People.day ASC'
    ));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In your People model**

```
public $virtualFields = array(
'month_day' => 'CONCAT(People.month, "-", People.day)'
// 'month_day' => 'CONCAT(People.day, "/", People.month)'
);
```

**then add in your controller**

```
$options = array(
   'conditions' => array(
       'Post.month_day  BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('01-03','01-06')
       // 'Post.month_day  BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('03/01','06/01')
   )
);
$posts = $this->Post->find('all',$options);
```

Comment: Wow, you gave me an incredible insight, I never quite understood virtual fields, but now I get it.

Comment: Ok, sorry, looks like it's my mistake, I'm using int on the BD and the code works for strings... gonna fix that

Comment: Ok, this answer is completely correct, I tried using day/month but didn't work... HOWEVER... month-day works flawlessly, so if you read this... go for the first option in the marked answer ok?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to alter your table. Use `DATE` field and your SQL query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbname.People
WHERE People.date BETWEEN '1999-03-01' AND '1999-06-01';
```

Comment: Yes I thought about this, but I don't want to modify the BD, unless is my only choice...